# Pass parameter to QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to use the following code bellow to fire multiple thread to consume an `HttpWebRequest`.
I do a `foreach` in all possible requests (each request has different data), but when I pass the request to the method of consumption, it seems that it only receives always the last item in the list.

Could someone help me fix this error ?

```
int pending = requests.Count;
var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
foreach (Request request in requests)
{
  // Required to close over the loop variable correctly.
  Request capture = request; 
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      try
      {
        ProcessRequest(capture);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pending) == 0) 
         {
           finished.Set();  // Signal completion of all work items.
         }
      }
    }, null);
}
finished.WaitOne(); //
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you pass your requests to threads as state object?
Just pass each request as second parameter to the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. That is a preferred way of passing data to the thread.

```
foreach (Request request in requests)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    state =>
    {
      try
      {
        ProcessRequest(state as Request);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pending) == 0) 
         {
           finished.Set();  // Signal completion of all work items.
         }
      }
    }, request);
}
```

Comment: +1: You might need to cast `state` back to `Request` before passing it to `ProcessRequest`. Assuming of course, that this is the expected parameter type the OP used. Just nitpicking ;-)

Comment: Is possible to call other methods inside the method that is calleable by the ProcessRequest?
It seems that the threads are lost when I make a call from another resource.

Comment: @tomcamara - Yes, just remember that they are being called on another thread and you should synchronize access to shared data if required.

Comment: @JakubKonecki can you provide me an example to sync this resource, my problem is exactly that, I need to access other resources, but I am getting the data as incorrect.

Comment: is possible to make a method I'm calling to be part of the thread that I'm creating?